# Помогите доделать задачу на python "Один из них"

Tags: python, алгоритм

это снова я с этой задачей. Огромное спасибо **Stanislav Volodarskiy**, за помощь в коде, но этот **код выполняет 14 из 26 тестов**. Я пытался сам улучшить код так, чтобы выдало больше баллов, но делал только хуже. Я бы оставил ссылку на сайт, но без спонсора вы на него не зарегистрируйтесь.
Вот задача:

> Александр работает на таможне в космопорте. Однажды туда прибыл
> космический корабль после экспедиции на Марс. Сканер в порту забил
> тревогу, на корабле находится ровно один марсианин, который
> замаскировался под члена экипажа. К сожалению сканер не способен
> показать, кто конкретно является марсианином.
>
> Тогда Александр решил запросить протокол общения всех членов экипажа.
> **Известно, что в языке реальных членов экипажа вероятность появления**
> **каждого символа зависит от предыдущего. Однако, марсианин этого не**
> **знал и пытался пародировать язык реальных членов экипажа, выбирая**
> **буквы независимо от предыдущих.**
>
> Помогите Александру определить, кто из членов экипажа на самом деле
> является марсианином. Гарантируется, что с имеющимся протоколом
> общения это реально сделать.

**Формат входных данных**

Первая строка содержит натуральное число `N (3 ≤ N ≤ 10)` — число членов экипажа на корабле (включая замаскированного марсианина).
Следующие `N` строк содержат текст высказывания соответствующих членов экипажа.
Каждая строка состоит только из маленьких латинских букв и пробелов. Сумма длин всех строк не превышает `10⁴`.

**Формат выходных данных**

Выведите одно натуральное число — номер строки, которая соответствует тексту высказывания замаскированного марсианина.

**Пример 1**

**Входные данные:**

```
3
aba caba 
aba daba
baa cdaa
```

**Выходные данные:**

```
3
```

Вот код, который решает **14 из 26 тестов**:

```py
import collections


def pairs(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    next(it, None)
    return zip(seq, it)


def frequences(seq):
    counts = collections.Counter(seq).values()
    s = sum(counts)
    return (c / s for c in counts)


def variance(seq):
    c = 0
    s1 = 0
    s2 = 0
    for v in seq:
        c += 1
        s1 += v
        s2 += v * v
    # print((s1 * s1 - s2) / c)
    return (s1 * s1 - s2) / c


def variances(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield variance(frequences(pairs(input())))


print(min((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(variances(int(input())), start=1))[1])
```

Comment: Привидите тест, который не проходит, в формате: входные данные такие то, ожидаем получить значение такое то, получаем такое то.

Comment: Вам может помочь кто-то кто знает прикладную статистику. Кажется тут две статистические гипотезы, надо сделать выбор.

Comment: @SwaD не могу это сделать, т.к. сайт не предоставляет этого

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за совет